Transaction context is not propagating to a new thread started transaction Spring Data Jpa
I have a method annoted by @Transactional, this method persists an entity and makes a for loop then for each loop it passes the persisted entity to an @Async method in order to persist a child entity based on that one. The main method just ends when all threads are done. An example below
@Transactional
private void mainMethod(Persisted entity,Param params){
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> processList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Item item:params.getData().getItems()){
        CompletableFuture<Void> process =  produtosPedidoProcessor.asyncPersistance(entity,item);
        processList.add(process);
    }
    CompletableFuture<Void> allProcesses = CompletableFuture.allOf(processList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    allProcesses.join();
}

And then the async method
@Async("someThreadPool")
public CompletableFuture<Void> asyncPersistance(Persisted entity,Item item){
    //massive api call
    someRepository.save(childEntity);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}

The problem is when I persist the child entity it gives me a foreign key error like the main entity was not persisted, it's clear that transactional context is not being propagated between those threads.
How can I handle async + transcational on this example in order to solve this error?
What I've tried:
I removed the persistance from thread, and returned a completable future cotaining unpersited state from child entity to then save it on thenApply:
    process.thenApply(result -> {
              someRepository.save(childEntity);
              return null;
            }).exceptionally(
                    e->{
                        return null;
                    }
    );

But the exceptions is always triggered, getting that foreign key error.

You forgot to ask a question. You statement is correct. Declarative transactions doesn't work with Async.

I've already added it sorry

Resolution:
Change the async method to:
@Async("someThreadPool")
public CompletableFuture<ChildEntity> asyncPersistance(Persisted entity,Item item){
    //massive api call
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(childEntityNotPersisted);
}

And the main method to:
@Transactional
private void mainMethod(Persisted entity,Param params){
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> processList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ChildEntity> childList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Item item:params.getData().getItems()){
        CompletableFuture<Void> process =  produtosPedidoProcessor.asyncPersistance(entity,item);
        process = process.thenApply(result -> {
            synchronized (produtos){
                childList.add(result);
                return null;
            }
        });
        processList.add(process);
    }
    CompletableFuture<Void> allProcesses = CompletableFuture.allOf(processList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    allProcesses.join();
    for(ChildEntity child:childList()){
        someRepository.save(childEntity)
    }
}

Conclusion
Use the async thread to make the heavy stuff then make a way to it return the processed data to main thread than do the persistance, persisting inside thenApply will not work as it's executed in the same thread as Completable Future

On what is "runApply" ?

Don't mark whole method with @Transactional.
Use TransactionTemplate to only add transaction when persisting entity.
First inject TransactionTemplate this bean is already available you can directly autowire it.
and use it inside async method like this:
transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(
                // persist entity
                 someRepository.save(entity)
        );

or
 var result = transactionTemplate.execute(
                    // persist entity
                 someRepository.save(entity)
            );

